# Flask-OAuth TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, facebook, flask, oauth, flask-oauthlib

I'm trying to use Flask-OAuth with Facebook following this [example](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-oauth/blob/master/example/facebook.py).
I have define **APP_ID** and **APP_SECRET** according to mine.

I can login with facebook account now, but when it redirects after login, I got this error:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

According to the example code if there are no edited, the line of error was on line 48

```
me = facebook.get('/me')
```

So, what's wrong with that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answers The **flask_oauth** library doesn't support Python3, instead I'm using **Flask-OAuthlib**.

And instead of the example code that I use in the link above, now I'm using the new one in this [example](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/facebook.py)

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of Flask-OAuthlib. It is suggested that you use Authlib instead.